# Is there a D7/Services module for sane field content I/O?

Tags: 7, services

For instance, a GET request to the standard endpoint `node/1.json` returns an object with fields like this:

```
{
   ...

   "field_my_field":{
      "und":[
         {
            "value":"yucky"
         }
      ]
   }

   ...
}
```

To build an easy to use API, we would want to GET and POST objects with fields like this:

```
{
   ...

   "my_field": "clean"

   ...
}
```

It would be easy to implement the vast majority of field types this way. I thought there was a module for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think there could be, fields are more complex than your desired output. e.g. there's a node field called `body`; if you were to add `field_body` as well, you'd immediately have a collision and one of the values would be lost. Similarly if it's multi-lingual, if the fields are multiple cardinality, have multiple columns, etc, they can't be generically represented in that way. I'd love to see a solution, though, I've been ruling Drupal out of API projects for exactly this reason lately

Answer (score 0):

With the [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module, no. However you could build a Page display with [Views datasource](https://drupal.org/project/views_datasource), that accepts a node id as a contextual filter. The fields you specify in the View can then be configured to "clean up" the property name (or just turn off the label to use the machine name of the field), and then the value will be "flat".